# Exhaustiveness check for pattern matching in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

We have some pattern matching code where we would expect to be warned by the compiler that the match is not exhaustive, but we get none. Are there some cases where the exhaustiveness check can't be done?

E.g Our example (using scalactic Good+Bad):

```
(maybeModelIdOrFailure, maybeMake) match {

    case (Some(Good(modelId)), Some(makeId)) if modelId >= 0 && taxonomyService.isValidModel(makeId, modelId) =>
      Good(Some(MakeModelParameters(makeId, Some(modelId), modelLineId = None, index)))

    case (Some(Good(modelLineId)), Some(makeId)) if modelLineId < 0 && taxonomyService.isValidModelLine(makeId, -1 * modelLineId) =>
      Good(Some(MakeModelParameters(makeId, modelId = None, modelLineId = Some(-1 * modelLineId), index)))

    case (Some(Good(modelOrModelLineId)), Some(makeId)) =>
      Bad(One(IdNotFound(modelIdKeyName, modelOrModelLineId)))

    case (Some(Good(modelId)), None) if modelId >= 0 =>
      Bad(One(IdInvalid(modelIdKeyName, "Model Id without Make Id")))

    case (Some(Good(modelLineId)), None) if modelLineId < 0 =>
      Bad(One(IdInvalid(modelIdKeyName, "Model Line Id without Make Id")))

    case (None, Some(makeId)) => Good(Some(MakeModelParameters(makeId, None, None, index)))

    // case (None, None) => Good(None)

    // case (Some(Bad(invalidParams)), _) => Bad(One(invalidParams))
  }
```

We commented the last two lines, but the compiler doesn't warn and we didn't disable any checks.

Comment: It could be related to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7631 (though it shouldn't have such effect by itself). You could try moving the guard conditions inside the branches (e.g. `case (Some(Good(modelId)), None) => if (modelId >= 0) ... else ...`) and checking if this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Jason Zaugg's comment on SI-9232](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9232?focusedCommentId=72153&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-72153) it seems the guards currently simply disable exhaustiveness checks (or nearly so). If that's the reason, moving the guard conditions inside the branches (e.g. `case (Some(Good(modelId)), None) => if (modelId >= 0) ... else ...`) should help. Other related issues: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5365, https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7631.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the scala just switch off the exhaustiveness check if you have any guard in the match. My compiler do not produce a warning even on this:

```
def tt(s: Option[Int]) = s match {
  case Some(x) if x > 0 => println(x)
}
```

As long as I keep the guard there. There are tickets with discussions on this:
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7631
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5365
And it looks like there is some work to be done here, so it might improve. Scala compiler can't check the guards exhaustiveness in most of the cases, because it is too complex thing to do, but your case definitely proves that it can be improved.

Comment: Yes thanks you're also right. But I already accepted the earlier answer. You've got a upvote from me though.

Comment: @longliveenduro Alexey's comment was the first one, I didn't notice it. So it's fine :)